# IP_RECVDSTADDR is not defined

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

error: IP_RECVDSTADDR undeclared (first use in this function), can I use this socket option with Linux or it is already is undefined I searched in all in.h files on linux but I could't find anything about it.

Steven is used it but he types

```
#ifdef IP_RECVDSTADDR 
.......
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's not defined for your implementation, then you can't use it.

The reason why the Stephens book uses the `#ifdef` is because you can't use it if it's not defined.

the option is a `BSD` specific option; It appears in Mac OS X and FreeBSD

Answer (score 2):

The preferred option is `IP_PKTINFO` yet the BSDs, and OSX, do not implement this for IPv4, of note they do implement it per the IPv6 standard with `IPV6_PKTINFO`.  Similarly of interest, Solaris defines both.

Thus you need per platform specific code for IPv4 handling.